# What `kubectl scale` does under the hood?

Tags: kubernetes

What actually happens when one writes the following on the google cloud console?

```bash
kubectl scale --replicas=10 deployment <deployment_label_name> -n <namespace>
```

I heard many times that "your deployment scales up" but I would like to know what happens under the hood. I checked that number of VMs in the cluster does not change so apparently amount of resources does not increase. So what exactly the scaling means then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scaling here refers to horizontal scaling, meaning *how many pods* should be deployed. This is typically defined with `.spec.replicas`, for a deployment.

So you can imagine, that all it does is updating the field `.spec.replicas` to the given number. This is merely a convenience function and could be done in a number of different way, too.

Comment: So where are those pods deployed? What if I have two nodes and I scale to 1000 replicas? In other words, why may someone need more replicas than nodes?

Comment: its up to you how you define your scaling. If you have max pods per node and resource requests/limits (QOS) properly set, kubernetes will run not 1000 pods on 2 nodes. Otherwise you probably break your nodes. Even 2 replicas on the same node can make sense, if you anticipate that your pod crashes, but not the node itself.

Comment: @hans, if you have autoscaling for your nodes enabled, and qos properly set, kubernetes WILL scale out the nodes, once you reach the resource cap of a given node.